# Error finding distance between two points using $geoNear in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, geolocation

I'm trying to find the distance between two points using $geoNear mongoDB function and receiving the following error:

> MongoError: error processing query: ns=Driveoo.vehiclesTree: GEONEAR
>   field=location maxdist=10000 isNearSphere=0↵Sort: {}↵Proj: {}↵ planner
>   returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear queryCar Search
>   Failed

Please find my code below:

```
exports.getNearestVehicles = function (req, res, next) {
    Vehicle.find({
      location: {
       $near: {
        $maxDistance: 10000,
        $geometry: {
         type: "Point",
         coordinates: [req.query.lat, req.query.long]
        }
       }
      }
     }).then( results => {
        return responseHandler.resHandler(true,JSON.stringify(results,0,2),"Car Response", res, 200);
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        return responseHandler.resHandler(false,null,error+"Car Search Failed", res, 200);
    });
}
```

Can anyone trouble-shoot where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create 2d sphere index before the query ?

You can create the index as follows

`db.createIndex({'location','2dSphere'})`

Also in above query you did not use geoNear, [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)
is generally used with aggregate.

Comment: Hi @sachin. Can you please give an example of how can I use $geoNear with aggregate to find the distance between two points? Yes I have created the 2d sphere index before the query

Answer (score 0):

Below code will get the distance between the two co-ordinates.

In Model file,

```
Location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point']
    },
    coordinates: [Number]
  },

ModelSchema.index({Location: '2dsphere' });
```

while in controller file,

```
exports.getDistances = async (req, res, next) => {
  
  const multiplier = unit === 'mi' ? 0.000621371 : 0.001;

  const distances = await Model.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [req.query.long*1, req.query.lat*1]
        },
        distanceField: 'distance',
        distanceMultiplier: multiplier
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        distance: 1,
        name: 1
      }
    }
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    data: {
      data: distances
    }
  });
});
```